# UI issue on localhost

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When I am trying to run my web-application in IE(8) using localhost it is not displaying it properly, but when I use 127.0.0.1 it works fine.

"Not displaying it properly" means that the alignment and spacing is not coming as expected. But it is coming properly when I use local IP address(127.0.0.1) instead of localhost.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

The screenshots are :

- By using localhost
  [image]
- By using 127.0.0.1
  [image]

Comment: In what way is it not displaying properly? Screen shots would be helpful.

Comment: Could you add some detail about how it is displaying incorrectly?

Comment: Define "not displaying it properly". In any case, check you hosts file for the definition of 'localhost' (should be 127.0.0.1).

Comment: How do you link to your CSS/JS/Images?

Comment: I am using ./js/jsFileName.js to link it with my jsp page.

Comment: Use Firebug 'Net' tab to see if there are any resources missing (returns HTTP 404 Not Found)

Answer (score 2):

Check your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) whether it contains a line for localhost:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

**EDIT:**

If you find a block with lines commented out like this...

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

...you are on Windows 7 and something is going wrong with the localhost resolution in your DNS. My guess is that you have a mixed IPv4/IPv6 environment, your DNS returns the IPv6 address for localhost (e.g. 2001:4860:4860::1234 – try a `nslookup localhost` on the command line) and some part of your installation does not support that IPv6 address.

Try to remove the # in front of the 127.0.0.1 and see if that cures the problem.

Comment: i have below lines in hosts file :                              # 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: Looks like you are on Windows 7. The # in front of the line makes it a comment which is ignored. See my edit above.

Comment: Should i restart the system after this change?

Comment: No. Not necessary. Try ``nslookup localhost`` on the command line before and after the change.

Comment: I just saw your edit on your original question. There is something else going on. Obviously localhost is resolved partially but not in all situations.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of localhost and IP access? What result do you get on ``nslookup localhost``?

Comment: Sorry, but this is really strange and I have no idea. My recommendation: Use Firefox with extension Firebug or the built-in developer tools in Google Chrome to check the elements (e.g. the back button and its parent elements) to see their CSS properties and their nesting and check where both versions differ from each other.